# During a question merge not all comments got merged into the master question

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, moderator-tools, merge-questions

I just merged [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/92682/cover-flow-license-issues#question) (10k+ link) into [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/92614/cover-flow-license-issues), but it looks like only my comment made it over into the master question and Vitor's comment was left behind.

Is that the expected behaviour?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks for leaving a comment that made me realize I was asking opposite things in the title and body. :) Rephrased the title now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During merge, some comments won't be moved to the master when

- they contain the word "duplicate"
- they contain a link to the master question